# Dynamically allocated array of strings memory doesn't seem to be working

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I'm trying to have this function read a sentence and store each word into an array of strings. I store the sentence in `line`:

```
char** storewords(char* line){    
    char** newArr = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*)); 
    free(word);
    return newArr;
}
```

I later call this function and try to print each word in the array:

```
main {
    // ........ //
    //function to get a line into line//
}

void printArr(char** newArr) {
    int i = 0; 
    }
}
```

I use `while (newArr[i] != NULL)` in order to tell the program to iterate through the array until encountering a `NULL` item.

The memory seems to be allocated weirdly, because when I print it out, some words don't seem to print sometimes but other times works perfectly.

For example, if I input "hello hi", I get:

```
newArr 0: 
newArr 1: hi
```

and "hello my name is" will get:

```
newArr 0: hello
newArr 1: my
newArr 2: name
newArr 3:
```

but if I input something longer like "hello my name is stackoverflow", I get the correct results.

Comment: Using `sscanf()` to copy a string is novel.  It works, but `strcpy()` or `memmove()` (or `memcpy()`) would be more conventional.

Comment: The `free(word)` is a no-op because `word` is NULL.  It's just as well really.  And your `newArr[count] = NULL;` writes beyond the end of the allocated space.

Comment: Please read and understand [the question on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in C](/q/605845).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the idea behind your `storewords` correct, you want to:

a) Start with a single char pointer

b) Add an extra char pointer each time you call `realloc`

so that you can set the last char pointer to NULL so that it serves as an "end-of-array" marker.

If that is your intention, the problem is the `realloc`.

```
char** newArr = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*));  // Now you have 1 char pointer
char* word;
int count = 0;  // Notice that you (correctly) initialize count to zero

word = strtok(line, " ");
while (word != NULL) {            
    newArr = (char**) realloc(newArr, sizeof(char*) * (count + 1));
                      // The first time you execute the realloc, you want to
                      // increase the number of char pointers from 1 to 2.
                      // But count is zero so count + 1 is only 1.
                      // In other words, you only got 1 element but
                      // you wanted 2 elements.
```

So instead do:

```
    newArr = (char**) realloc(newArr, sizeof(char*) * (count + 2));
```

as `count` is "2 behind" the number of elements you want.

BTW: Doing `realloc` directly into destination variable is bad. Always do it in two a temp variable. Check for NULL. If not NULL, assign the temp variable to the destination.

BTW: No need to cast the value returned by `realloc` and `malloc`

BTW: Remove `free(word);` It does nothing and you don't want to free anything here.

So with the above in mind, your function could be:

```
char** storewords(char* line){    
    char** tmp;
    char** newArr = malloc(sizeof(char*)); 
    char* word;
    int count = 0;

    word = strtok(line, " ");
    while (word != NULL) {            
        tmp = realloc(newArr, sizeof(char*) * (count + 2));
        if (tmp == NULL)
        {
            // realloc failed - add error handling - for now just exit
            exit(1);
        }
        newArr = tmp;
        newArr[count] = malloc(strlen(word) * sizeof(char) + 1);
        // put the word in array
        sscanf(word, "%s", newArr[count]);
        count++;

        word = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    newArr[count] = NULL; //set the last item in the array as null
    return newArr;
}
```

Comment: You missed the part where you check the result of `realloc()` *before* assigning it to `newArr` (so you don't lose/leak the original when allocation fails).  And you can remove the cast of the returned pointer.

Comment: @TobySpeight 1) Regarding `realloc`: I actually didn't miss the part. Did you read the BTW. 2) Regarding the cast: This is a direct copy of OPs code with only the change needed to make it work. I prefer answering with code as close to OPs code as possible. Hence the cast. Anyway, I added a complete function with all fixes.

Answer (score 0):

while you play with string you should be always very careful. Here you are using pointer of pointer so use them like pointer rather use as array and mix and match. While you write a program, arrange the algorithm first how you are going to implement it step by step and write it down in a paper, which is call as `procedural design` as well. I have modified your program below see your mistakes here. Also see how I just use the pointer of pointers as pointer only but not like array. So I leave the code for `printArr` to you to change it from array to pointer so that you can enjoy it. GOOD LUCK!!

```
char** storewords(char* line){
    char** newArr = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*));
    char* word;
    int count = 1;
    word = strtok(line, " ");
    *newArr = word; //store the pointer of word at the first location
    while (word != NULL) {
        newArr = (char**) realloc(newArr, sizeof(char*) * (count + 1));
        //newArr[count] = (char*)malloc(strlen(word) * sizeof(char) + 1);//you dont need this line at all
        // put the word in array
        //sscanf(word, "%s", newArr[count]);
        word = strtok(NULL, " ");//get the next word
        *(newArr+count)=word;//store the next word here
        count++;

    }
    *(newArr+count) = NULL; //set the last item in the array as null
    free(word);
    return newArr;
}

void printArr(char** newArr) {
    int i = 0;
    while (newArr[i] != NULL) {
        printf("newArr %d: %s\n", i, newArr[i]);
        i++;
    }
}

int main() {
    // ........ //
    //function to get a line into line//
    char *line = malloc(100);
    strcpy(line, "Hello world how are you!");
    char** newArr = storewords(line);
    printArr(newArr);
    return 0;
}
```